# Incorrect syntax near 'PK' error when attempting to insert into SQL Server database

Tags: php, sql-server, yii2

Database Exception – yii\db\Exception

```
Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => HY000
    [1] => 102
    [2] => Incorrect syntax near 'PK'. [102] (severity 15) [INSERT INTO [ORDERS] ([ID], [STATUS], [ZIPFILE], [COLOR], [PRICE]) VALUES (87, 1,'PK]
    [3] => -1
    [4] => 15
)
```

> ↵
> Caused by: PDOException
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 102 Incorrect syntax near 'PK'. [102] (severity 15) [INSERT INTO [ORDERS] ([ID], [STATUS], [ZIPFILE], [COLOR], [PRICE]) VALUES (87, 1,'PK]

In a yii2 app, I am trying to upload a zip file using file_get_uploads php function to first convert the zip into binary and saving it into the 'ZIPFILE' column in the SQL Server database, but am receiving the above error.

Looks like the special characters after PK is truncating the value of ZIPFILE and anything that comes after it in the SQL insert string. If I were to escape the special characters by using the PHP `addslashes()` function, I am able to complete the insert, but the zip file gets corrupted because of the additional slashes. Changing encoding is not an option as I use another app to download the data from the database and that app requires the values to be in this encoding.

Is there a way to escape the special characters without corrupting the zip file?

I'm including some of the code to make things a bit clearer.

App uses Yii2 framework

controller Code

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Orders();
    $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())
   
    //populates ZIPFILE property with binary value of the ASCII encoded ZIPFILE string(pre-populated) compressed to a .zip file and read using file_get_contents in the Zip model
    $model->ZIPFILE = (new Zip)->asBinaryString($model->ZIPFILE);
    
    if ($model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->ID]);
    } else {
        return $this->render(
            'create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
    }
}
```

In the Zip model

```
private string $_tempFolder = '/somecache/';

public function asBinaryString($content): ?string
    {
        $fileName = $this->create($content);
    
        $fileAsBinary = file_get_contents(Yii::$app->basePath . $this->_tempFolder . $fileName);
        
        return $fileAsBinary;   
    }

public function create($content): ?string
    {
        $zipName = \microtime();
        try {
            $zip = new \ZipArchive;
            if ($zip->open(Yii::$app->basePath . $this->_tempFolder . $zipName, \ZipArchive::CREATE) === true) {
                $zip->addFromString(time().'.RTF', $content);
                $zip->close();
            } else {
                throw new Exception(Yii::t('app', 'Archive could not be created in cache folder.'));
            }
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            throw $th; 
        } 
        return $zipName ?? null;
        
    }
```

The string loaded back into $model->ZIPFILE looks like this "PKa��PM?ٟ�1590409143.RTFu��n�0�_e`���Os�R��j���*�Ƅ�A"�5Dݨʻ�@0......"

Storing the file on to disk with the link in the database is not possible as this is an enhancement to a legacy app which requires the data to be stored as a zip in the database.

Attempted to reach closer to a solution by converting the binary zip to hex using PHP bin2hex(), but not successful. The hex does not have the special characters; hence, the $model gets saved fine, except that the zip file saved to SQL server is not readable by the other app.

This is not a simple Typo issue and using prepared statements here has been tried, but does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me at least 10 days of extensive searching on the web and testing out various solutions before this could be solved.

The answer to the above problem is that is **NOT POSSIBLE** to save a binary string directly into a SQL Server database. The file needs to be sent as a `hex` string.

Solution:

```
public function asBinary($content): ?string
{
    $fileName = $this->create($content);
    $fileAsBinary = file_get_contents(Yii::$app->cache->cachePath . '/' . $fileName);
    return $fileAsBinary;   
}

/**
* zips file in cache folder into archive
*/
public function create($content): ?string
{
    $zipName = \microtime();
    try {
            $zip = new \ZipArchive;
            if ($zip->open(Yii::$app->cache->cachePath . '/'  . $zipName, \ZipArchive::CREATE) === true) {
                $zip->addFromString(time().'.RTF', $content);
                $zip->close();
            } else {
                throw new Exception(Yii::t('app', 'Archive could not be created in cache folder.'));
            }
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        throw $th;
    } 
    return $zipName ?? null;      
}

//return file as Hex string
public function asHex($content): string
{
    $fileAsBinary = $this->asBinary($content);
    $unpackedBinaryFile = unpack('H*hex', $fileAsBinary);
    $fileAsHex = '0x' . $unpackedBinaryFile['hex'];        
    return $fileAsHex;   
}
```

Populate ZIPFILE in $model

```
$model->ZIPFILE = (new Zip)->asHex($model->ZIPFILE);
```

The zip file needs to be converted to a `hex` string which can be directly saved into SQL Server. SQL Server would convert it into `VARBINARY` when inserting into database.

For reasons that are not clear I could not pass ZIPFILE using Yii2's prepared statements. Would error out each time. Also, couldn't save using ActiveRecord's `$model->save()` method. Had to insert using SQL query string. Would be great if someone can tell why.